# Using same cocoapod across framework and app iOS

Tags: ios, ios8, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I created a custom framework that uses AFNetworking Pods. The framework works fine on my application. But, when I try to include the same pod to application project, I see the following debug message upon simulator launch

> objc[3660]: Class AFURLSessionManager is implemented in both
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I am getting this error for all the files of the pod that I have included.

The basic problem statement is:
Custom framework A has file with name "ABC.h" that defines class ABC. The project in which A is integrated also has file with the name "ABC.h" and defines class ABC.

I tried keeping "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" as YES in both framework and the sample app, but still the same issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am stuck in a similar situation. Did you find a solution for this question? Please let me know